# remove double quotes around "function() { ... }"

Tags: php, regex

Brain not working today - can anyone give me a regexp that would turn:

```
 {events:{click:"function() { alert('hi'); }"}}}}}
```

into:

```
 {events:{click:function() { alert('hi'); }}}}}}
```

any any other instances such as this in a string.

if this helps expand my question:

So far using this:

```
$replacement = '${1}:';
$json_options = preg_replace('/"(\w+)"\s*:/', $replacement, $json_options);
```

I have it turn this:

```
string(1051) "{"chart":{"renderTo":"tx_count","defaultSeriesType":"spline"},"credits":{"enabled":false},"series":[{"type":"spline","name":"Transactions Per Day","color":"#4572A7","data":[3,5,3,3,3,6,6,92,2]},{"type":"spline","name":"Value Per Day","yAxis":1,"color":"#89A54E","data":[30,232,172.99,30,160,550,596,2407.96,20]},{"type":"spline","name":"Average Value Per Day","yAxis":2,"color":"#AA4643","data":[10,46.4,57.7,10,53.3,91.7,99.3,26.2,10]}],"legend":{"enabled":true},"xAxis":{"labels":{"rotation":"-45"},"categories":["02\/02\/2011","03\/02\/2011","06\/02\/2011","07\/02\/2011","08\/02\/2011","09\/02\/2011","10\/02\/2011","11\/02\/2011","14\/02\/2011"]},"title":{"text":"Transactions Summary","align":"center","x":0,"y":20},"yAxis":[{"title":{"text":"Transactions","style":{"color":"#4572A7"}}},{"title":{"text":"Value","style":{"color":"#89A54E"}},"opposite":true},{"title":{"text":"Value (Average)","style":{"color":"#AA4643"}},"opposite":true}],"plotOptions":{"series":{"cursor":"pointer","point":{"events":{"click":"function() { alert('hi'); }"}}}}}"
```

into this (which is perfect),

```
string(947) "{chart:{renderTo:"tx_count",defaultSeriesType:"spline"},credits:{enabled:false},series:[{type:"spline",name:"Transactions Per Day",color:"#4572A7",data:[3,5,3,3,3,6,6,92,2]},{type:"spline",name:"Value Per Day",yAxis:1,color:"#89A54E",data:[30,232,172.99,30,160,550,596,2407.96,20]},{type:"spline",name:"Average Value Per Day",yAxis:2,color:"#AA4643",data:[10,46.4,57.7,10,53.3,91.7,99.3,26.2,10]}],legend:{enabled:true},xAxis:{labels:{rotation:"-45"},categories:["02\/02\/2011","03\/02\/2011","06\/02\/2011","07\/02\/2011","08\/02\/2011","09\/02\/2011","10\/02\/2011","11\/02\/2011","14\/02\/2011"]},title:{text:"Transactions Summary",align:"center",x:0,y:20},yAxis:[{title:{text:"Transactions",style:{color:"#4572A7"}}},{title:{text:"Value",style:{color:"#89A54E"}},opposite:true},{title:{text:"Value (Average)",style:{color:"#AA4643"}},opposite:true}],plotOptions:{series:{cursor:"pointer",point:{events:{click:"function() { alert('hi'); }"}}}}}"
```

now i need to remove double quotes round any function() { ... stuff... } that may be in the string.

Comment: Do you just want to remove every quotation mark?

Comment: nope just around any:thing: “function() { .some other code... }”

Comment: You want to remove the first and the last quote in the string? How do the quotes get into that string in the first place? Can you prevent them from getting into there? If the solution by Briedis below is not solving your question, please update it to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php preg_replace('/"(function\s*?\(\)\s*?{.*?})"/', "$1", $string); ?>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! Both valid so accepting both (tho i had done the alternative one before i posted anyway!).

Answer (score 5):

You can `$string = str_replace('"', "", $string);`, no need for a regexp in this particular example.

Or try this then:

```
$string = str_replace(array('"function()','}"}'), array('function()', '}}'), $string);
```

Comment: I am trying to hack some json together for highcharts, so neex to keep double quotes round values but not values that are 'functions' as such.

Comment: Yes I have done it that way - but I was wondering if there was any case in the string where replacing }" would be a false positive and break it :)

Comment: Yes, thats why I replace }"}, not just "} What is the possibility for that?